# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'black' compilation error but the pdf is fine

Tags: color, packages, texstudio

So I get this Package xcolor Error but I'm already using the color package which should include the color black but I still get this message.

I've tried multiple other solutions on this forum already but they were no good. The weird thing is that the pdf turns out fine while I still get the Error in the log.

Also this is the first time I'm using this forum so please bear with me.

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{bm}

\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667}
\definecolor{UBCgrey}{rgb}{0.3686, 0.5255, 0.6235}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=UBCblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=UCBblue}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=UBCblue}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=UBCblue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=UBCgrey,fg=white}

\title[Abbildungsfehler von Linsen und Objektiven]{Abbildungsfehler}
\subtitle{von sphärischen Linsen und Objektiven}
\author{Muller, Mittmann, Kotur, Ling}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square]
\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[square]

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=black !10}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=black !5}

\begin{document}

\AtBeginSubsection[] 
{
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Inhalt}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame} 
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Inhalt}
    \tableofcontents[pausesections,pausesubsections]

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Abbildungsfehler}
    \begin{block}{Monochromatische Abbildungsfehler}
        Alle Abbildungsfehler, die bei einfarbigem Licht auftreten. Monochromatisch = einfarbig, gleiche Wellenlänge
    \end{block}

    \pause

    \begin{block}{Chromatische Abbildungsfehler}
        Alle Abbildungsfehler, die bei Mischlicht auftreten. Mischlicht = mehrfarbig, unterschiedliche Wellenlänge
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{Monochromatische Abbildungsfehler}

\subsection{sphärische Aberration}
\begin{frame}
    Nicht alle Lichtlinien treffen sich an einem Punkt, -> sphärische Aberration entsteht.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Koma}
\begin{frame}
    Inhalt...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Astigmatismus}
\begin{frame}
    Inhalt...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Bildfeldwölbung}
\begin{frame}
    Inhalt...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Verzeichnung}
\begin{frame}
    Inhalt...
\end{frame}


\section{Chromatische Aberrationen}

\subsection{Farblängsfehler}
\begin{frame}
    Inhalt...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Farbquerfehler}
\begin{frame}
    Inhalt...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) No need to load the packages `graphicx` and `xcolor` they are loaded by `beamer`. A minimal document doesn't produce this error: `\documentclass[]{beamer} \begin{document} \color{black}foo \end{document}`

Answer (score 6):

### First color error

The first error message is:

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `UCBblue'.
```

It is caused by a misspelling:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=UCBblue}
```

because the color is defined

```
\definecolor{UBCblue}{rgb}{0.04706, 0.13725, 0.26667}
```

with the name `UBCblue` instead of `UCBblue`.

### Second color error

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `black '.
```

Notice the space at the end of the color name. It is caused by:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=black !10}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=black !5}
```

The color `black␣` with the space at the end is not a standard color or defined in the document. Removing the space fixes the issue:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=black!10}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=black!5}
```